# Do ProCurve 2800's (2810 to be exact) have an ACL or access-list command?

Tags: access-control-list, hp

I have setup access-lists in my 2610 and 3400 but can't find a way to do it in my 2810s. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

The [Access Security Guide](http://ftp.hp.com/pub/networking/software/2810-Security-Jul2006-59914734.pdf) for the 2810 switches should tell you what you want. I'm assuming that by "ACL" you're referring to the switch making decisions on passing traffic based on layer 2 (MAC or ethertype) or layer 3 (protocol, ports, etc) characteristics of the packets. I think you're going to be disappointed.

The gist, as I'm reading it, is that these are fairly unsophisticated layer 2 switches. They don't appear to have any type of filtering functionality beyond using the source switch-port number in a simplistic drop / pass filter mechanism.

Comment: OK. This is kind of what I was thinking would be the answer. I will have to go another route. Thank you!

Comment: +1 Correct, the 2810 is meant to be an edge access switch, it does not include much filtering or anything above layer 2.